# RTSP Camera P2P Connection without Port Forwarding and Console Application

Tags: python-3.x, rtsp, p2p, hikvision

I am trying to connect Remote RTSP Stream from IP Camera, but unable to get it without port Forwarding or Client Application. Is there any procedure to connect RTSP stream from one network to other network without port forwarding?

I have already tried with application client from *hikvision* and checked *Wireshark* streams but unable to get it

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Nabto P2P platform](https://www.nabto.com), it is designed exactly to solve this problem, free for personal use and test / R&D. [The Nabto blog](https://www.nabto.com/category/video/) has specific examples for setting up RTSP P2P tunnelling on cameras, Raspberry Pi devices and ESP32 devices:

You can either install the Nabto P2P reverse proxy in front of your RTSP service on the camera as a standalone process - or you can integrate it into an existing application. Full source is available in [github](https://github.com/nabto/unabto/tree/master/apps/tunnel).

On the client side, you can use an existing Nabto enabled RTSP client - or build your own based on the client SDKs, available for most popular platforms. Existing client apps available in github and in App store / Google Play.